Android phone has taken 2 system updates today, 2 more this month
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S32 FE 5G, which is currently running Android 14.
The phone has taken system updates twice today, and at least a couple of more times this month.
It looks like something's going on here. How would I figure out what? Is there somewhere on my phone or online where I can go to look up what's the deal with all these constant updates this month?

Weirdly, when I tried picking the samsung-galaxy-s21 tag from the completions (literally clicking on it from the list, not typing it in manually), I'd get an error saying I don't have enough rep to create that tag. If someone feels this should have that tag, and you have more than 300 rep, feel free to add it.

I used the manufacturer tag as given all of Samsung's models, it would become unmanageable otherwise. Have you seen: https://security.samsungmobile.com/securityUpdate.smsb

I did see this Android patch page, which lists patches on the 1'st and the 5th. That jibes with my memory of roughly when I took the previous 2 patches this month, but doesn't explain either of the two I got today.

If I'm reading my settings->system->software information right, it appears I have the May 1'st patch, but not the May 5th one.
